# <gazebo/gui/GuiPlugin.hh> is missed?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I built the source file from [GUI Overlay tutorial](http://www.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gui_overlay&cat=user_input), there was a fetal error that <gazebo/gui/GuiPlugin.hh> is missed. So I looked into the include directory and found there was no such a header file. I searched on the Internet and hardly got anything, so I am stuck here and need some help. I installed gazebo-4.0 from the source code a few days ago and still was not familar with it. Did I missed something when I installed it? Or something else? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7323/%3Cgazebo/gui/guiplugin.hh%3E-is-missed?/) by [BenWashburn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1004/benwashburn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-10-29**:
Which source file? And, can you post the console output?

**Comment by [BenWashburn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1004/benwashburn/) on 2014-10-29**:
Thanks.  https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/examples/plugins/gui_overlay_plugin_spawn/     Here's the link of the source code. After the cmake step, I met the following errors when make it--fatal error: gazebo/gui/GuiPlugin.hh: No such file or directory.--  In the path /usr/local/include/gazebo4.0/gazebo, there exist other header files like <gui.hh> and <Plugin.hh> but no <GuiPlugin.hh>.   So I have no idea what has gone wrong.

**Comment by [BenWashburn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1004/benwashburn/) on 2014-10-29**:
Here's the total console output:
In file included from /home/ben/gazebo_gui_spawn/build/moc_GUIExampleSpawnWidget.cxx:9:0:
/home/ben/gazebo_gui_spawn/build/../GUIExampleSpawnWidget.hh:21:35: fatal error: gazebo/gui/GuiPlugin.hh: No such file and directory
#include <gazebo/gui/GuiPlugin.hh>
compilation terminated
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gui_example_spawn_widget.dir/moc_GUIExampleSpawnWidget.cxx.o] error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gui_example_spawn_widget.dir/all] error 2
make: *** [all] error 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The GuiPlugin.hh header file is not present in gazebo4 and earlier. You must use the default branch (or gazebo_5.* or later branches once they are created).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BenWashburn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1004/benwashburn/) on 2014-10-30**:
Thanks a lot. That's quite helpful.

**Comment by [mohammadkassemzein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7182/mohammadkassemzein/) on 2018-11-09**:
So how can I use  "Overlay Gui" in earlier version of gazebo (e.g. gazebo2)

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-11-09**:
You can't, you must upgrade Gazebo.